# Create Django view just for testing

Tags: django, django-testing

We are writing a new decorator that will test for the presence of an authentication token in the request headers. The request is created by posting data to a URL. There are currently no views that use this decorator. The views are likely to be in a different module anyway. So is there a way for me to create a view, attach it to a URL then wrap the decorator around it just for the sake of testing the decorator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a test url conf that includes your decorated view, then use the [`TestCase.urls`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/testing/overview/#django.test.TestCase.urls) option to use it in your test class.

Comment: So the view is a real view with no URL in the main conf (hence inaccessible normally) but a url in the test conf?

Comment: Yes, include the view in your test url conf but not your regular url conf.